# Free particle Schrödinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Some sources give the free-particle solution to Schrödinger equation as

$$\psi(x,t) =Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} + Be^{-i(kx+\omega t)}$$

while some sources give it as

$$\psi(x,t) =Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$

Are they the same? I can't see that they are the same thing, especially when we try to find the probability distribution function for both of them. They just don't seem to give us the same probability when we integrate the PDF.

What am I missing out here?

Comment: This is a duplication of your [previous quesion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105454/free-particle-solution-to-schrodinger-equation).  Please edit your previous question, or comment on the answers rather than opening a new question.  I think you will find the answer to this question on your previous one.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution is the first one you gave, 
$$\psi(x,t) =Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} + Be^{-i(kx+\omega t)}.$$
To get to the second one, you need to impose appropriate boundary conditions, which essentially means having no incoming particle flux from $+\infty$.

Alternatively, you can see the solution 
$$\psi_k(x,t) =Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$
as general enough to reproduce the first one if you allow for superpositions of $\psi_k$ and $\psi_{-k}$. In particular, anything that depends linearly on $\psi_k$ will also hold for the superposition, so that sometimes it is easier to only keep one half of the wavefunction and then add in (the linear response to) the other one at the end.